# Oracle Query To Fetch Records Based On A Constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in the below format:

```
ID    FieldA   LastUpdatedDate

1      1       7th Oct, 2014
2      2       7th Oct, 2014
3      3       7th Oct, 2014
4      1       8th Oct, 2014
5      2       8th Oct, 2014
6      1       8th Oct, 2014
7      2       9th Oct, 2014
8      4       9th Oct, 2014
```

I would want the result to be as shown below:

```
ID    FieldA   LastUpdatedDate
4      1        8th Oct, 2014
6      1        8th Oct, 2014
2      2        9th Oct, 2014
3      3        7th Oct, 2014
8      4        9th Oct, 2014
```

Please note that there can only be two entries having the same values in FieldA for a given date and I would want to 
retrieve entries based on the `lastupdateddate` as shown in the example.

Could you please suggest a query that gives me results like this ?

Comment: Can you explain the logic you used to produce this result (in English, not in SQL, obviously :-))

Comment: I would want to obtain records having duplicate fields and non duplicate fields based on the latest date available in the table. Also, I do want to sort the entries based on the FieldA cited in the above example. If you examine the example cited here, there are 3 records with value = 1 for FieldA. I would want to obtain records having the latest updated date. Here, I would get 2 records with value 1 for FieldA, both with lastupdateddate on 8th Oct, 2014.

Comment: Along with this, I would want other entries like records with value 2, 3 and 4 for FieldA as they show their lastupdatedDate respectively. Please do let me know if this helps in understanding what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, for each different value of `fieldA`, you'd like to display only the records from the last `LastUpdatedDate`. The [`rank`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm) analytic function should do the trick:

```
SELECT ID, FieldA, LastUpdatedDate
FROM   (SELECT ID, FieldA, LastUpdatedDate,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, FieldA 
                            ORDER BY LastUpdatedDate DESC) AS rk
        FROM   my_table)
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: @RS389 I seem to have been missing the `ID` column in the `partition by` clause. I've edited my answer to include it - try now.

Comment: I tried something like this - Select ID, FieldA, LastUpdatedDate from my_table where LastUpdatedDate  in (Select max(LastUpdatedDate) from my_table) order by FIELDA;

Answer (score 0):

```
with lastD as  -- get the last update date for every FieldA
(
select FieldA, max(LastUpdateDate) as lastDate
from my_table
group by FieldA
)
SELECT m.*
FROM   my_table m
JOIN   lastD
  ON   m.FieldA=lastD.FieldA
 AND   m.LastUpdateDate= lastD.lastDate
```

Comment: Care to provide some details/explanations?